# Serving a vCard (.vcf) file through Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can deliver a file through Iron Router. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1) User opens URL like http://website.com/vcard/:_id
2) Meteor generates vCard file

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Gump;Forrest;;Mr.
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:(404) 555-1212
ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100 Waters Edge\nBaytown\, LA 30314\nUnited States of Ameri
 ca
ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown\, LA 30314\nUnited States of Ame
 rica
EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
REV:2008-04-24T19:52:43Z
END:VCARD
```

3) User gets .vcf file and it runs on their phone, Outlook, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

it has little to do with iron router. You need something that can return simple text file. Here is a demo which kind of does that:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/TbjQfAnmTAFQcyZ5a/Leaderboard